# Biblatex not working for me on Overleaf

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, apa-style, overleaf

Newbie problem here, but for some reason I just cannot make Biblatex work on Overleaf, although I've entered all the proper commands, could someone help me out ?

Citation does not appear properly, and bibliography doesn't print at the end

Code applied to example below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{example}
\author{cameron}
\date{May 2020}

\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Morin220520.bib}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
There is a theory which states that if ever anyone discovers exactly what the Universe is for and why it is here, it will instantly disappear and be replaced by something even more bizarre and inexplicable.
There is another theory which states that this has already happened.
\cite[][]{traugott_constructionalization_2013}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1.7]{universe}
\caption{The Universe}
\label{fig:universe}
\end{figure}

\section{Conclusion}
``I always thought something was fundamentally wrong with the universe'' 

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Which documentclass do you use?

Comment: Hi, thanks ! Sorry the first line of code got skipped. I am using the article document class, but I've had the same problem with basic Beamer slide presentations.

Comment: Please clarify what "I just cannot make Biblatex work on Overleaf" entails. What are you getting at present? Are there any warning or error messages? If so, what do they say? Are the two `\section` commands, the `\maketitle` instruction, and the `figure` environment shown in your example related to the issue at hand?

Comment: also show the entry traugott_constructionalization_2013  in the bib file and any error you got in the log

Comment: Hi ! Just added a screen cap showing my pdf. Basically the citation is not formatted, and here are the logs :

Comment: 1 )Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file: output and rerun LaTeX afterwards.         2) You have referenced something which has not yet been labelled. If you have labelled it already, make sure that what is written inside \ref{...} is the same as what is written inside \label{...}.          3) Empty bibliography on input line 31               4)You have cited something which is not included in your bibliography. Make sure that the citation (\cite{...}) has a corresponding key in your bibliography, and that both are spelled the same way.

Comment: And here is the bib entry (which has worked well with natbib in the past): 

@book{traugott_constructionalization_2013,
 address = {Oxford},
 title = {Constructionalization and {Constructional} {Changes}},
 publisher = {Oxford University Press},
 author = {Traugott, Elizabeth and Trousdale, Graeme},
 year = {2013}
}

Comment: PS: no warnings or errors with respect to  \section, \maketitle and figure

Comment: Sorry forgot to tag you @Mensch

Comment: forgot to tag @Mico

Comment: and @DavidCarlisle as well

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem was an error in the source file (see the answer by the OP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out the source of the problem while looking into my error messages. There were syntax errors in my bib file (involving out of place brackets and parentheses) that I had to solve to let Biber run on my file. Once that was done, my PDF was compiled successfully with the reference! thanks